# How to prove that a statement is a theorem using Hilbert's system?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm looking for an actual step-by-step way of proving that a statement is a theorem using Hilbert's system. For instance:

[image]

As can be seen from the above picture, the solution consists in a series of steps starting from one of the three axioms (I can only use P2, P3 and P4 and Modus ponens from this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms). However, how do I know which axiom to start with? Should I go backwards, starting from the actual statement provided and work my way until I find an axiom? I've also seen ways where you use Modus Ponens (a, a->b/b), but it's unclear exactly the process.

Can anybody help me with the actual step-by-step process on how to do this?

Comment: *Modus ponens* is used in most of the steps of the derivation above. The third step is derived with the *tautology* $\vDash [\lnot C \to (B \to (A \to B))] \to [B \to (\lnot C \to (A \to B))]$ that, by *Completenss*, gives : $\vdash \ldots$ and the second step with *mp*.

Comment: Hilbert-style proof system is not easy to find proof; you have to build-up a basic "catalogue" of theorems (tautologies) and meta-theorems (like the *Deduction Th*) and re-use them. You can see Geoffrey Hunter, [Metalogic : An Introduction to the Metatheory of Standard First Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=oHpMtskGcv0C&pg=PA71) (1971), page 71-on.

Comment: But how do I proceed with the actual solving process? Do I start from the bottom, or from the top?

Comment: You have to use other proof systems, like *Tableaux* or *Sequent calculus*; they provide bottom-up procedures for proving theorems.

Comment: But Tableaux will only tell me if it's valid/invalid. Here I actually have to show whether it's a theorem

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/971608/174538) answer and also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318530/174538) one might help to shed you some light on proofs in a Hilbert-style system.

Comment: By completeness, if it is *valid*, it is *provable* and Tableaux is a *proof procedure*, like *Natural Deduction* and *Sequent calculus*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way of doing these, from the bottom-up, starting from the statement provided without having to induce anything upfront. First off you should look into some algebra for this system (which is deduced from the main 3 axioms) here: https://it.wikibooks.org/wiki/Logica/Calcolo_delle_proposizioni/Sistema_di_Hilbert#Regole_derivate - it's in italian but what matters are the actual properties.

Now, let's say you're given a statement and you have to show it's a theorem in Hilbert's system. First thing is you write it down your page so you can write stuff on top of it:

- $¬(A → B) → (B → C)$

Whenever you're confronted with something like $¬(A → B)$ - a NOT of two terms - you have to find a way to get rid of the NOT in front of it either by using the *contrast* property where $A → B$ is equal to $¬B → ¬A$, or by using the so called *exchange of premises* property where $A → (B → C)$ is equal to $B → (A → C)$. So from the above we go ahead and apply the exchange of premises property and exchange the $¬(A → B)$ with the $B$:

- $B → (¬(A → B) → C)$
- $¬(A → B) → (B → C)$

We moved it inside so we can get rid of the NOT, which as I said earlier, should be our main goal. In fact, now that $¬(A → B)$ is inside, we can apply the contrast property to help us negate it and therefore get rid of the NOT as such:

- $B → (¬C → (A → B))$
- $B → (¬(A → B) → C)$
- $¬(A → B) → (B → C)$

Great so remember that our goal is to continue this process until we find a statement which is an instance of one of the 3 axioms of Hilbert (linked in the question). It seems we're getting close to match Axiom P2 $A → (B → A)$, if we just move the B inside:

- $¬C → (B → (A → B))$
- $B → (¬C → (A → B))$
- $B → (¬(A → B) → C)$
- $¬(A → B) → (B → C)$

Now we simply need to move ¬C out and we matched our P2 Axiom and therefore showed that the initial statement was in fact a theorem.

- $¬C \vdash B → (A → B))$
- $¬C → (B → (A → B))$
- $B → (¬C → (A → B))$
- $B → (¬(A → B) → C)$
- $¬(A → B) → (B → C)$

Comment: Interesting approach.  Did you prove each of the rules that you used here first using just substitution and detachment?  Also, (¬C→(B→(A→B))) is a special case of a more general theorem.